# How to start up angularjs - rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to make a angularjs-rails app.

this is the flow what i have done.

```
rails new myapp
rails g scaffold Post body:string title:string
rake db:migrate
```

ok, now the backend for post's CRUD is ready.

now is for the angular part.

https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
bundle install
```

in javascripts/application.js

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-route
```

ok, setup is ready bothside.

now, i have to add angular codes.

in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cannaBlog">
<head>
  <title>UseAngular</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in app/assets/javascripts/angular/app.js.coffee

```
angular.module('cannaBlog', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider'
    ($routeProvider) ->
      $routeProvider
      .when '/posts',
        template: '/app/assets/javascripts/angular/templates/posts/index.html',
        controller: 'postsCtrl'
      .otherwise
        redirectTo: '/posts'
      return
  ])
```

in app/assets/javascript/angular/controllers/posts_controller.js.coffee

```
angular.module('cannaBlog', [])

.controller 'postsCtrl', ($scope)->
  $scope.yourName = "first"
```

in app/assets/javascripts/angular/templates/posts/index.html

```
this is index page
```

done!

now if i type the url

```
localhost:3000/posts
```

it only goes to the `rails routes` and shows the json data

```
[{"id":1,"title":"123","body":"123","created_at":"2014-09-24T09:25:12.173Z","updated_at":"2014-09-24T09:25:12.173Z"}]
```

What am i missing in here?

=====
update

i googled a little and add this code in the rails part application_controller.rb

```
  before_filter :render_single_page

  def render_single_page
    render 'layouts/application' if request.format == Mime::HTML
  end
```

now, it bootstraps all the angular files, but still display nothing when

type `/posts`, i think there is a problem with the angular-route part :(

but no errors are shown

Answer (score 0):

Try pass `postsCtrl` as a dependency in your app.js file. This will render your template using controller. This should show some error.

```
angular.module('cannaBlog', ['ngRoute', 'postsCtrl'])
  .config(['$routeProvider'
    ($routeProvider) ->
      $routeProvider
      .when '/posts',
        template: '/app/assets/javascripts/angular/templates/posts/index.html',
        controller: 'postsCtrl'
      .otherwise
        redirectTo: '/posts'
      return
  ])
```